# Can I pass props from a deeply nested child component to a parent component's api call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, nested

I would like to update the "{word}" in the api calls to trigger the responses from another component nested three components down "onClick". Do I need to use redux or would another method of context work?

I have previously attempted to use redux to do this but I couldn't get the "{word}" to change. I also attempted to move the api call into the store but then found I couldn't execute any of the responses.

````
  function handleResponse(response) {
    setResult(response.data[0]);
  }
  function handlePexelsResponse(response) {
    setPhotos(response.data.photos);
  }
  function search() {
    let apiUrl = `https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/${word}`;
    axios.get(apiUrl).then(handleResponse);

    const pexelsApiKey = `563492ad6f91700001000001f8c251ed6a594872bacfe286e28414e4`;
    let pexelsUrl = `https://api.pexels.com/v1/search/?page=1&per_page=6&query=${word}`;
    let headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${pexelsApiKey}` };
    axios.get(pexelsUrl, { headers: headers }).then(handlePexelsResponse);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    search();
  }

  function wordSearched(event) {
    setWord(event.target.value);
  }

  if (loaded) {
    return (
      <div className="dictionary">
        <section>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              autoComplete="off"
              placeholder={props.suggestedSearch}
              onChange={wordSearched}
            />
          </form>
          <div className="suggested-search">
            suggested searches: forest, embroidery, stein, fascinator...
          </div>
        </section>
        <Result result={result} />
        <Photos photos={photos} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    load();
    return "loading...";
  }
}```
````

Comment: Hope [Lifting state up might help you ... or you can consider context too](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd recommend you is to move all of your api calls into service folder. Then you can use React Context as well. Store your prop (which you has to pass from child to parent) in that context and every time your prop changes trigger API call.